# How to convert from old Confluence 3.5 markup to markdown?

Tags: markdown, confluence, wiki-markup

For historical reasons, we still have a large number of `*.confluence` files in the old Confluence 3.5 markup format. This format is not very useful (e.g. no editor support, no repository viewer support, ...), so I want to convert the files to markdown.

So how can I convert Confluence 3.5 markup to markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is the following, partially manual process:

1. Create an empty wiki page in a current version of Confluence (5.x or later) and save it.
2. Edit the page again.
3. Go to "Insert" > "Markup" and insert the Confluence markup
4. Click on "Open in source editor" to show the content in the new XML-based storage format
5. Copy the content to an XML file
6. Add the missing header and footer (see https://github.com/highsource/confluence-to-markdown-converter/issues/8)
7. Convert the XML file to markdown using the [c2md.xsl](https://github.com/oberlies/confluence-to-markdown-converter/blob/master/xslt/c2md.xsl) XSLT transformation from the [confluence-to-markdown-converter](https://github.com/oberlies/confluence-to-markdown-converter) Github project.

---

The key idea in this solution is to convert the old Confluence markup to the new Confluence XML-based storage format first. Once converted to XML, further conversions are reasonably easy (assuming you know XSLT) and quite robust.

I also tried out the Node-base [confluence2markdown](https://github.com/pborenstein/confluence2markdown) converter, but the converter [fails to parse the Confluence markdown reliably](https://github.com/pborenstein/confluence2markdown/issues/2).

So using Atlassian tooling for parsing the Confluence markup seems to be the way to go. This step can probably be further automated by using the [Atlassian SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started), but I haven't explored this option yet.